# Unable to increase AWK's int-limit for factorial

Tags: integer, awk, factorial

I run the [AWK code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787858/unable-to-make-a-factorial-function-in-awk) and I get

```
The factorial of 200 is inf
```

This suggests me that AWK does not use the same int IEEE-standard -module as Python.
It seems that AWK's limit is 170!.

**How can you make AWK understand as large integers as Python?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#fn-23):

> The internal representation of all numbers, including integers, uses double-precision floating-point numbers. On most modern systems, these are in IEEE 754 standard format.

Python can have integers of [any length](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), depending on available memory. This is independent of IEEE 754. BTW, that standard gives the limit of a double precision float at about 10^(+/-308). The value of log10(factorial(171)) is > 309. See also [Double Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) and [What Every Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/800-7895).

Comment: @Dennis: IEEE 754 seems to be the same format which Python uses. -- I use the newest OS/X. It may the reason why AWK cannot calculate 200!, but Python can.